# Cohomology of the Lagrangian Grassmannian

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, symplectic-geometry

I was wondering if some of you cold provide me with a reference where I can find what the cohomology ring of the Lagrangian Grassmannian of $\mathbb{C}^n$ looks like. In particular, I would need to know whether the second cohomology group $H^2(\Lambda(n); \mathbb{Z})$ is zero or not.

To give a bit of context, I have been reading the paper by Viterbo "Intersection de sous-variétés lagrangiennes, fonctionnelles d’action et indice des systèmes hamiltoniens" (one can find it [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266598410_Intersection_de_sous-varietes_lagrangiennes_fonctionnelles_d%27action_et_indice_des_systemes_hamiltoniens_Intersection_of_Lagrangian_submanifolds_action_functionals_and_indices_of_Hamiltonian_systems)), and more specifically the proof that if the first Chern class of a symplectic vector bundle is 2-torsion, then there exists a cohomology class which induces the Maslov class on the fibres. The idea of the proof is to use the Serre spectral sequence for a quotient of the classifying bundle for $U(n)$, and then apply results which can be found in the collection "Cohomologie des espaces localement compacts d'apres J. Leray" by Armand Borel to deduce that there is such a class if it lies in the intersection of the kernels of all the differentials $d_k$ applied to elements in $E^{0, 2}_2$. One therefore needs to prove that $d_2(\mu)=\pm 2c_1$, where $\mu$ is the Maslov class $\mu\in H^1(\Lambda(n); \mathbb{Z}).$ The piece I miss to do so is exactly that $H^2(\Lambda(n); \mathbb{Z})=0$, or that the differential there is injective (which looks harder to prove).

Comment: I think $H^2(\Lambda_n;\mathbb{Z})$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Is this consistent with Viterbo's paper? I'm afraid the French language is well above me.

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you for your answer! I do not know whether it is consistent or not with it, as the author does not really provide an indication of why $d_2(\mu)=\pm c_1$ (he mentions instead that $H^1(BO(n); \mathbb{Z})=0, H^1(BO(n); \mathbb{Z_2})=\mathbb{Z}_2$, but in my ignorance of spectral sequences I do not see how this influences the behaviour of the differential $d_2$ on $E^{0, 2}_2$). Would it be possible for you to point out a reference for $H^2(\Lambda(n); \mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2$, or let me know the reason of your opinion? I genuinely do not know a lot of the subject.

Comment: I know very little symplectic geometry.  Is the "Lagrangian Grassmannian" in the paper given by the space $Sp(n)/U(n)$ as described in wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_Grassmannian?  If so, then $H^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  One way to see this is to note that the LES in homotopy groups associated to the fibration $U(n)\rightarrow Sp(n)\rightarrow Sp(n)/U(n)$ shows $\pi_1(Sp(n)/U(n)) = 0$ and $\pi_2(Sp(n)/U(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Now use the Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: I just glanced through the paper and saw that the author writes that $H^1(\Lambda(n);\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so my previous commment is definitely wrong.  So, new guess:  is the Lagrangian Grassmannian $U(n)/O(n)$?  This would be consistent with $H^1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito thank you for your answer, but unfortunately (I should have specified it), I need the result for the real version $\Lambda(n)\cong U(n)/O(n)$, whose first homotopy group is already non-trivial (otherwise there would be no Maslov class, by Hurewicz theorem).

Comment: I think I made a mistake before. It should be $H^2\Lambda_n=0$. The differential $d_2(\mu)=2\cdot c_1$ is easy to compute using edge homomorphisms. If you haven't had any experience, then use the exact sequence on p. 145 of McCleary's book. Now use the Universal Coefficient Thm to get $H^2BO_n=\mathbb{Z}_2$. This means that the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor corresponding to the cokernel of the differential just computed must be the unique class survive to $E_\infty$ in total degree $2$. This implies that $H^2\Lambda_n=0$.

Comment: Note that $H^*(\Lambda_n;\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong\Lambda(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is an exterior algbra on classes of degree $|x_k|=k$ (they are the images of the Stiefel-Whitney classes).

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you, I will try to do so!

Comment: I got the same answer as @Tyrone (using bundles, but not spectral sequences), but my answer was too long for a comment.  Hence the answer below.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $SO(n)$ is normal and index $2$ in $O(n)$, we may view $U(n)/O(n)$ as $\left(U(n)/SO(n)\right) / \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now, let $f:U(n)\rightarrow SU(n)\times S^1$ be the diffeomorphism (which is NOT a group homomorphism) $f(A) = (B,\det A)$ where $B$ is obtained from $A$ by multiplying the first row of $A$ by $\det A^{-1}$.

Now, use $f$ to transport the $O(n)$ action on $U(n)$ to $SU(n)\times S^1$, i.e., we define an action of $O(n)$ on $SU(n)\times S^1$ by $C\ast(A,z) = f(C\ast f^{-1}(A,z))$.

Note that if $C\in SO(n)$, then the second coordinate of $C\ast(A,z)$ is $z$.  Further, for $g:=diag(-1,1,1,...,1)\in O(n)\setminus SO(n)$, the second coordinate of $g\ast(A,z)$ is $-z$.

So, viewing $U(n)/O(n)$ as $\left((SU(n)\times S^1)/SO(n)\right)/\mathbb{Z}_2$, we see that it's of the form $\left((SU(n)/SO(n))\times S^1\right)/\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Further, from the computation of $g$ above, we see that $g$ acts on this space diagonally, using the usual antipodal map on the $S^1$ factor.  In other words, this bundle is the associated bundle to the usual covering $\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow S^1\rightarrow S^1$.

Using the associated bundle construction, it follows that $U(n)/O(n)$ is a bundle over $S^1$ with fiber $SU(n)/SO(n)$.  From here, we see $\pi_1(SU(n)/SO(n)) = 0$ since $SU(n)$ is simply connected.  Thus, the LES in homotopy groups associated to $SU(n)/SO(n)\rightarrow U(n)/O(n)\rightarrow S^1$ now shows that $\pi_1(U(n)/O(n)) = \mathbb{Z}$.  Hurewicz and universal coefficients give $H^2(\Lambda(n);\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion free.

Thus, $H^2(\Lambda(n);\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ iff $H^2(\Lambda(n);\mathbb{Q}) = 0$.  Using the transfer homomorphism, we will be done showing $H^2(\Lambda(n);\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ if we show that $H^2(U(n)/SO(n);\mathbb{Q}) = 0$.  This space is diffeomorphic to $SU(n)/SO(n)\times S^1$, and $SU(n)/SO(n)$ has $\pi_1 = 0$ and $\pi_2 = \mathbb{Z}_2$.  It follows that $$H^1(SU(n)/SO(n);\mathbb{Q})\cong H^2(SU(n)/SO(n);\mathbb{Q}) = 0.$$  Kunneth now gives the final answer that $H^2(U(n)/SO(n);\mathbb{Q}) = 0$, so we are done.